# Select ListView GroupStyle Items

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, groupstyle

I have a *ListView* with *GroupStyle* in UWP like in the example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView/cs/Samples/SimpleListViewSample). I have the following *HeaderTemplate*:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
    <Grid Tapped="Header_Tapped">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

and I can get the selected *Key* by

```
private void Header_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var selItem = (sender as Grid).DataContext as GroupInfoList;
  var selKey = selItem.Key;
}
```

Now my problem is that despite knowing the selected *Key*, I cannot access the *Items* from it. In Debug, I can see the *Count* Property and it is equal to the number of elements, that are inside the Group, but I do not know, how to iterate through it.

I would very much like to iterate through all Items, that have the same Key as **selKey** and set a boolean property called **_isVisible** for all those items. What is a good/fast/effective way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupInfoList` is derived from `List<object>`. It contains all the `Contact` with the same `Key`. When you get `selItem`, you can use following code to iterate through it like iterate through a `List`.

```
foreach (var item in selItem)
{
    var contact = item as Contact;
    //suppose you have add a _isVisible property in Contact
    contact._isVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: This works fine. I was trying that too, but forgot the cast and was wondering why... Thank you very much!